# Find the lowest number of samples for which the kernel matrix is singular

Tags: machine-learning, matrix, kernel-trick, linear-algebra

The question is as follows:

Let $X$ be a matrix where the entries are natural numbers between 1
and $m$ $( X ∈ \{1 , 2 , 3 , . . . , m\}^{d×n} )$, $m >> 0$, $d$ is the number of features and $n$ is the
number of data points $(n >> 0)$ . Let also $K \in \mathbb{R}^{n×n}$ be the kernel matrix deﬁned
by $K_{i,j} = k( X_{\bullet ,i}, X_{\bullet,j} )$, where $k : \mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the kernel function and $\forall l,  X_{\bullet,l}$
is the lth column of $X$.
What is the lowest value of $n$ that guarantees the kernel matrix $K$ is singular for any matrix $X$ and for any kernel function $k$?

This is my approach so far:

A matrix is singular if the determinant is zero, i.e. if one eigenvector is zero,
since the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues.
Since every kernel matrix is PSD, we can diagonalize it as follows:

$$
K = P\Delta P^{-1}
$$

Now $\Delta$ is a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues on it's diagonal.
Since every PSD matrix contains only non-negative eigenvalues, we can break this equation down even further:

$$
P\Delta P^{-1} =  P\sqrt{\Delta}\sqrt{\Delta} P^{-1} = P\sqrt{\Delta}P^{-1}P\sqrt{\Delta} P^{-1} = \sqrt{K}\sqrt{K}
$$

where $\sqrt{\Delta}$ is the element-wise application of the square-root.

Now we know that $K$ and $\sqrt{K}$ have the same eigenvectors, but I'm sort of stuck at this point.

Am I moving in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two identical input vectors, then you will have a singular matrix, regardless of $k(\cdot,\cdot)$, because you will have a matrix with a pair of duplicate rows/columns.  In this case the input vectors are essentially strings from a finite alphabet, so there are $m^d$ possible strings and therefore, by the ["pigeon hole principle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), if $n = m^d + 1$ you are guaranteed to have a singular matrix.